# Npm Revert sudo permissions to default?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, npm

I followed this article https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions (SECOND OPTION IN PAGE) to be able to install global modules without having to use `sudo`

It works, but now i would like to revert permissions to use `sudo` again, do you have any advice or clue for this? Do i have to uninstall node and npm ?

I am on a mac osx thank you for any help.

Comment: What option did you pick? If you changed owner of directories, you can change it back to root like: `sudo chown -R root $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}`

Comment: second option sorry i update with this information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Option 1:**

Change directories owner back to root
`sudo chown -R root $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}`

**For Option 2:**

Change npm prefix back to default (in many cases including OSX default is `/usr/local`), remove folders and env variables.

Assuming you named directories and files like in manual:

```
npm config set prefix '/usr/local'
rm -r ~/.npm-global
rm ~/.profile
```

If you set `NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX` env variable:

```
unset NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX
```

Note about *PATH* variable:
It should be fine after reboot, also you can manually set it to value without `~/.npm-global/bin` section.

Comment: +1 this seems to be worked well, should i accept it i don't know i would... will wait for some more feedback maybe but i think i'll accept it!